# Как узнать момент, когда на странице загрузились шрифты?

Tags: javascript, html, веб-программирование

windows.onload не подойдёт, т.к. шрифты при слабом интернете загружаются и отображаются не сразу, и уже после загрузки страницы. Я бы хотела сделать, чтобы до момента загрузки шрифтов отображался экран загрузки. Это возможно вообще сделать?

Answer (score 1):

document.fonts.ready.then(…); является решением ;)